# amazon aws ec2 find public address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I applied for jobs and in that resume i mentioned my AWS IP But what someone who knew my IP registered and wrote bad words all over.The recruiters rejected me.

Only 14 people know my IP address and anyone can register in that.How can i catch him?

Everything inside website is under my control.

Comment: There are automatic bots that scan aws public IP ranges looking for vulnerabilities. Can setup a captcha to limit auto-posting things to your website, and setup WAF for your load balancer or cloudfront distro.

Comment: What was running on that IP address? Was it an Amazon EC2 instance? What software was serving web content on the server? What do you mean by "registered"? Please edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, More than 14 people know your public IP address.

Amazon EC2s are granted public IPs from [published IP address ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

Furtermore, [Port scanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner) is largely automated these days, and some port scanners can do things like automatically exploit known vulnerabilities in unpatched public services.

secondly, I'm guessing you were running something like Wordpress on an ec2 with a public IP address, then handing that out.  This is like walking through a tiger-infested forest wearing a meat suit and shouting.